# how to get something from my database to appear on my django html project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to get a quote from my database to appear on my html webpage using django. IT will not appear

here goes my index.html file **the code on this website put the quotes around my answer. in my program its no quotes on it. Other than that , the code is exactly how it appears in my file.:

`{%extends 'homepage/layout.html' %}`

`{% block content %}`

`{% for quote in quotes %}`

`<h2>{{quote.body}}</h2>`

`{% endfor %}`

`{% endblock %}`

Here goes my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
class Quote(models.Model):
def __str__(self):
return self.body
```

Here goes my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Quote
def index(request):
quotes = Quote.objects.all()[:1],
context = dict()
context['quotes'] = quotes
return render(request, 'homepage/index.html', context)
```

When i run this, I get no errors. Its's just the quote that is stored in the database does not display on the screen .

BUT When i run this in my index.html file :

```
{%extends 'homepage/layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for quote in quotes %}
<h2>{{quote}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

it displays the quote as a query set object. So I do know the quote can be referenced and my project is connecting to the database. Im just not understanding why the way im doing it is not working.

the quote is ""To uncover the truth, we must ask ourselves before we ask anything else, is it true?—True to the motives, the impulses, the principles that shape the life of actual men and women?""

Any help please?

Comment: In your views.py you have a comma at the end of the `quotes = ...` line. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the comma from the end of the following line in your views.py file:

```
quotes = Quote.objects.all()[:1],
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's your problem. I set up a test environment with your `views.py` and template code and experienced the same as you described. Removed the comma and things worked correctly.

Comment: could you tell me how to center it ? is it <h2 class=center-align>?

Comment: `<h2 style="text-align: center">` will do it. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!